# linker command failed in react native app, using react-native-firebase

Tags: xcode, react-native

I developed a react native app using react-native-firebase library.
I want to set my app icon, so I used this library:`npm install -g yo generator-rn-toolbox` from [here](https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/change-your-react-native-app-icons-in-a-single-command-line).

When I try to build the project I receive this error:

`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTSRWebSocket", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libReact.a(RCTInspectorPackagerConnection.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTReconnectingWebSocket", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libReact.a(RCTPackagerConnection.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Same issue when building an expokitbased app for an ios 11 device.

Answer (score 13):

I fixed it by manually adding the RCTWebsocket library:

1. find the RCTWebsocket project: `open -R node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/RCTWebSocket.xcodeproj`
2. Drag it into xcode under your projects Libraries folder
3. on your project, select your project target, then goto "Build phases" --> "Link Binaries With Libraries" --> "+"
4. Search for `libRCTWebSocket.a` and add it

your project should build now. If `libRCTWebSocket.a` in step 4 is not there, try to build the project first.

Comment: I just followed the 3rd and 4th steps, Its got fixed, Thanks @macrozone :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the similar issue for iOS 12, XCode 10.
For those that may help (and avoid losing days like me..),
i had to add the `libRCTWebSocket.a` and the `libfishhook.a` binaries in the YourProject -> Targets -> YourProject -> `Link Binary With Libraries` list

Comment: You deserve a medal for that! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to build the app by placing libRCTWebSocket.a before libReact.

[image: xcode linker settings]

Comment: finally! this did the trick, but in the test target (after a full day)