# React Native iOS: undefined symbols for architecture

Tags: ios, react-native

I know there are quite a few threads about this, but none seemed to help for me so far. My problem is i am getting a linker error for debug builds: `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:`.

I used to have the opposite problem of duplicate symbols when trying to archive (debug was working then), i then noticed and removed duplicate dependencies manually linked and mentioned in my podfile (namely a lot of react native `RCT...`). Afterwards i was able to archive, but not to debug build anymore.

I tried a lot of different solutions, but i am still getting the same error. I have `CxxBridge` included in my podfile, i do `clean` before i try any of the solutions. But still no luck so far. This is very annoying at the moment. Does anybody have an idea?

[image: error]

Comment: What is the exact issue? can you please add some screenshot?

Comment: Hi, i added the screenshot. The exact issue is, that debug build cannot find symbols that would normally come from cocoapods. As i workaround i have added a separate target where i additionally linked the pods react native library manually, which works for debug builds but not for archive builds (which in turn would bring a `duplicate symbols` error, instead of missing).

Comment: Bro, please check first answer over there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504825/linke-command-failed-in-react-native-app-using-react-native-firebase

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort, but that is not the solution. As i mentioned manually linking the libraries result in archiving to be broken, because of duplicate symbols. So this does not help. What i wan't to achieve to use Pods, not manually linking.